# MS SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

При попытке подключиться к серверу MS SQL Server 2014 через «проверку подлинности Windows» появляется ошибка:

> Соединение с сервером
>
> Невозможно подключиться к ***\***
>
> Дополнительные сведения: не удалось исполнить вход. Имя пользователя
>   принадлежит недоверенному домену и не может использоваться в проверке
>   подлинности Windows (Microsoft SQL Server, ошибка: 18452)

Как от неё избавиться и успешно подключиться?

[image: Экранный снимок окна подключения с ошибкой]

Comment: См. [здесь](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555332/login-failed-for-user-error-message-when-you-log-on-to-sql-server). Что дополнительно в логе написано?

Comment: Ваш пользователь windows добавлен как пользователь для этого экземпляра sql server?

Comment: @insolor `пользователь windows` это имя компьютера ? а где добавить для этого экземляра ?

Comment: @Dev18 пользователь, под которым логинитесь в системе. Где добавить - вероятно в 2019 я это знал, но уже забыл. Возможно как-то через MS SQL Management Studio зайдя просто через пользователя/пароль

Comment: не получается просто пользователь/пароль. Просит имя сервера, начала устанавливать сервер, там FireWal ошибку выдает, создала правило...путь не тот чтоли...совсем че то запуталась. Раньше и правда вроде легче было. У меня на этом компе не было sql, решила установить так че то пока невыходит. Вот ищу похожую задачу, может кто решил на просторах уже @insolor

Comment: Тут я не помогу, я примерно с 2019 как раз с MS SQL и не работаю.

Comment: оставлю здесь...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX5kmjaJNck&ab_channel=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8IT%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0 ссылка с ютуба, скачивать sqlserver и если есть предупреждение про FireWall нажмите дальше...потом создайте правило https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver16 и потом выберите уже из списка в sqlManagementStudo ваш Сервер //имя сервера и имя правила то же

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте запущен ли служба MSSQL попробуйте подключиться напрямую по IP